# php regex escape character dotcomma

Tags: php, regex

This regular expression checks for alphabetic, numeric and basic symbols:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 :,.-\s\?\!()]+$/
```

I need to add the ";" character, but how can I do this, can't find how to escape that one \; is not working.

Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

Just noticed as pointed out by @Tim Pietzcker, you don't need to escape `?` and `!` but `-`  needs escapting since it creates ranges:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 :,.\-\s?!();]+$/
```

---

There is no need escapting it in that character class, add it directly:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 :,.-\s\?\!();]+$/
```

Comment: You also don't need to escape `?` or `!` here. But you do need to escape the dash (or move it to the end of the class).

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Thanks for spotting that, didn't notice it. Updated.